# How to implement proper column major perspective projection matrix?

Tags: c, glsl, vulkan

I'am drawing a quad on the screen successfully when using this vertex shader code:

```
#version 450
#extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects : enable
#extension GL_EXT_debug_printf : enable

layout (location = 0) in vec3 in_position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 in_tex_coord;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 in_normal;

layout (set = 0, binding = 0) uniform TkSceneUniform
{
    mat4    Projection;
    mat4    View;
} Scene;

layout (push_constant) uniform TkModelPushConstant
{
    mat4    Transform;
} Model;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(in_position, 1.0);
}
```

By the way I'am using Vulkan API for drawing, shader language is GLSL, programming language is C, platform in Windows 10 x64.

But I have nothing on the screen after applying perspective projection and view matrices to the vertex position in the vertex shader if those are not identity matrices.

```
...
void main()
{
    gl_Position = Scene.Projection * Scene.View * Model.Transform * vec4(in_position, 1.0);
}
```

My perspective projection implementation in C (took it from there https://vincent-p.github.io/posts/vulkan_perspective_matrix/):

```
TkMat4 tkPerspectiveProjection(float32_t FOV_Radians, float32_t AspectRatio, float32_t NearClip, float32_t FarClip)
{
    const float32_t FocalLength = 1.0f / tkTan(FOV_Radians / 2.0f);

    const float32_t X = FocalLength / AspectRatio;
    const float32_t Y = -FocalLength;
    const float32_t A = NearClip / (FarClip - NearClip);
    const float32_t B = FarClip * A;

    const TkMat4 Projection = tkMat4(tkVec4(X, 0,  0, 0)
                                   , tkVec4(0, Y,  0, 0)
                                   , tkVec4(0, 0,  A, B)
                                   , tkVec4(0, 0, -1, 0));

    return Projection;
}
```

TkMat4:

```
// 00 01 02 03 | ix jx kx Tx
// 10 11 12 13 | iy jy ky Ty
// 20 21 22 23 | iz jz kz Tz
// 30 31 32 33 |  0  0  0  1
#define TK_MAT4_ORDER

// 00 10 20 30 | ix iy iz 0
// 01 11 21 32 | jx jy jz 0
// 02 12 22 32 | kx ky kz 0
// 03 13 23 33 | Tx Ty Tz 1
#define TK_MAT4_MEMORY_LAYOUT
typedef union TK_ALIGN(64) TkMat4
{
    TkVec4    col[4];
    float32_t m[16];

    struct
    {
        float32_t m00, m10, m20, m30;
        float32_t m01, m11, m21, m31;
        float32_t m02, m12, m22, m32;
        float32_t m03, m13, m23, m33;
    };
} TkMat4;

TkMat4 tkMat4(TkVec4 Col0, TkVec4 Col1, TkVec4 Col2, TkVec4 Col3)
{
    return (TkMat4) { Col0, Col1, Col2, Col3 };
}
```

TkVec4:

```
typedef union TK_ALIGN(16) TkVec4
{
    float32_t val[4];

    struct
    {
        union { float32_t x, r, s; }; // 1 element
        union { float32_t y, g, t; }; // 2 element
        union { float32_t z, b, p; }; // 3 element
        union { float32_t w, a, q; }; // 4 element
    };
} TkVec4;

TkVec4 tkVec4(float32_t X, float32_t Y, float32_t Z, float32_t W)
{
    return (TkVec4) { X, Y, Z, W };
}
```

Vertices of the quad are defined as follows:

```
...
TkVertex3d Vertices[TK_TEST_VERTEX_COUNT] = { 0 };

const float32_t Factor = 1.0f;

Vertices[0].Position.x =  0.5f * Factor;
Vertices[0].Position.y = -0.5f * Factor;

Vertices[1].Position.x = -0.5f * Factor;
Vertices[1].Position.y = -0.5f * Factor;

Vertices[2].Position.x = -0.5f * Factor;
Vertices[2].Position.y =  0.5f * Factor;

Vertices[3].Position.x =  0.5f * Factor;
Vertices[3].Position.y =  0.5f * Factor;
...
```

Matrices i use when got nothing on the screen:

```
const TkMat4 Projection = tkPerspectiveProjection(TK_DEG_TO_RAD(45.0f), 16.0f/9.0f, 0.1f, 1000.0f);

const TkMat4 View = tkMat4_Translation(tkVec3(0, 0, -10.0f)); // Returns identity matrix except col[3] x y and z are equal to those of the specified vector.

const TkMat4 Transform = tkMat4_Identity(); // Identity matrix.
```

Result (nothing on the screen, only clear color):

[image]

However if i use identity matrices only - i have my quad on the screen as if no transformations applied to it, so the multiplication itself works correctly I assume:

```
const TkMat4 Projection = tkMat4_Identity();

const TkMat4 View = tkMat4_Identity();

const TkMat4 Transform = tkMat4_Identity();
```

Result (quad as i expect it, it looks like rectange because of the window aspect ratio 16/9):

[image]

I have tried to use different values for the View z component between -1000 and 1000.
I have tried to use factor values for vertex position between 1 and 1'000'000.
When i inspect matrices in break mode - the values seems to be correct.
Checked matrix values in the shader itself - they seems to be correct there too.

What i expect is to see quad with the perspective applied to it, so it would look like a quad considering 16/9 aspect ratio.

My guesses:

- Something wrong with my perspective projection implementation.
- I use row major order instead of column major.
- I use wrong coordinate system heandness.

Please help me solve this.

Answer (score 0):

As i suspected, my perspective projection was wrong.

So this implementation did the trick for me instead:

```
TkMat4 tkPerspectiveProjection(float32_t FOV_Radians, float32_t AspectRatio, float32_t NearClip, float32_t FarClip)
{
    const float32_t FocalLength = tkTan(FOV_Radians / 2.0f);

    const float32_t X = 1.0f / (AspectRatio * FocalLength);
    const float32_t Y = 1.0f / FocalLength;
    const float32_t Z = -((FarClip + NearClip) / (FarClip - NearClip));
    const float32_t A = -1.0f;
    const float32_t B = -((2.0f * FarClip * NearClip) / (FarClip - NearClip));

    const TkMat4 Projection = tkMat4(tkVec4(X, 0, 0, 0)
                                   , tkVec4(0, Y, 0, 0)
                                   , tkVec4(0, 0, Z, A)
                                   , tkVec4(0, 0, B, 0));

    return Projection;
}
```

Do not ask me how it works, have no idea.

By the way coordinate system assumed to be right handed and Z-axis pointing to the screen.